# C# Microsoft Interop Excel 1997-2003 VBA Macros: Double Click Event Into Cell Not Working

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop

Our company has an old Excel 1997-2003 VBA application (.xls). If you doubleclick particular cells in the sheets, macros are executed. This is working totally fine if I manually open the file and doubleclick the cell, then the macro is executed.

However, in my C# code I am trying to open the .xls with the microsoft.office.interop.excel.application object. Opening works fine but when I doubleclick the cell, they don't execute the macro but jump into cell editing instead...

This is the VBA Sub that is executed upon Double-Click into a cell:

```
    Sub DblClickHandle()
   z = ActiveCell.Row
    Select Case Cells(1, 256)
        Case "1009":   'Bearbeitungs-Stati
            Call SchutzAus
            Select Case ActiveCell.Column
                Case 2:   'Position bearbeiten
                    Worksheets("AP-Bearbeitung").Activate
                    Call SchutzAus
                    Cells(z, 4) = Format$(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY")
                    Call SchutzEin
                    Select Case Cells(z, 2).FormulaR1C1
                        Case "Protokoll erzeugen"
                            If Existiert("Deckblatt") = True Then Call ReSet_AP
                            Call AP_Erstellen
                        Case "Export":
                            Call AP_Export
                        Case "Finanzierungsbestätigung"
                            Call CreateFinBest
                        Case "Ausdruck mit Preisen":
                            Call AP_Print(True)
                        Case "Ausdruck ohne Preise":
                            Call AP_Print(False)
                        Case "Ausdruck in PDF mit Preisen"
                            Call AP_PDF(True)
                        Case "Ausdruck in PDF ohne Preise"
                            Call AP_PDF(False)
                        Case "Einzelblattausdruck mit Preisen":
                            Call AP_DruckenEinzeln(True)
                        Case "Ausdruck mit Blattauswahl"
                            Call AP_Mehrfachdrucken
                        Case "Einzelblattausdruck ohne Preise":
                            Call AP_DruckenEinzeln(False)
                        Case "Laufzettel"
                            Call AP_Laufzettel
                        Case "Abtretung und Zahlungsanweisung"
                            Call CreateAbtZahAn
                        Case "Abtretung bei öffentl. Förderung"
                            Call CreateAbtZahAnÖ
                        Case Else
                            On Error GoTo errhandle779
                            Worksheets(Cells(z, 2).FormulaR1C1).Activate
                            On Error GoTo 0
                    End Select
                Case 1, 5:
                    If Cells(z, 10) Then
                        Cells(z, 5).FormulaR1C1 = ""
                      Else
                        Cells(z, 5) = Format$(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY")
                    End If
                Case 4:
                    If Len(Cells(z, 4).FormulaR1C1) > 2 Then
                        Cells(z, 4).FormulaR1C1 = ""
                      Else
                        Cells(z, 4) = Format$(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY")
                    End If
            End Select
            Call SchutzEin
        Case "1099":     'Pakete für Laufzettel
            Call SchutzAus
            If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ý" Then
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "¨"
                Call SchutzEin
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "¨" Then
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ý"
                Call SchutzEin
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Call SchutzEin
        Case "1999"
            Call BeiTasteEinfg
            Call SchutzAus
            Select Case ActiveCell.value
            Case "Kellerbaufirma":
               Cells(23, 1).value = "Keller fertig am"
            Case "Fa. Bodenplatte"
               Cells(23, 1).value = "Bodenplatte fertig am"
            Case "Keller fertig am"
               Cells(19, 1).value = "Kellerbaufirma"
            Case "Bodenplatte fertig am"
               Cells(19, 1).value = "Fa. Bodenplatte"
            Case Else:
            End Select
            Call SchutzEin
        Case Else:
            Call BeiTasteEinfg
    End Select
    Exit Sub
errhandle779:
    MsgBox Error()
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

I have googled everything to find a similar problem but didn't find anything.
Could you please assist me in fixing this issue?

```
#Here is my C# code in which I am opening the .xls macro file with excel interop:

var xlapp = new Excel.Application();
xlapp.Visible = true;                        
xlapp.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityByUI;
xlapp.EnableEvents = true;
xlapp.Workbooks.Open(@"\\serverxy\bemuster\ap\" + "KV" + txtHv.Text + @"\" + "Ap.xls")
```

Comment: Is there a "DoubleClick" method somewhere in that file's VBA and if so, where is it located? Something like `Application.DoubleClick="SomeFunction"` just CTRL+F "DoubleClick" in the VBA IDE for the whole project

Comment: It is located in a VBA module: `Sub EnableRedirections()
   
    Application.OnDoubleClick = "DblClickHandle"
'    Rufe Auto_Öffnen sendkeys
End Sub`

Comment: @jamheadart : This did not fix the issue. Cells are still being edited instead of executing the macro.

Comment: Try calling the macro that activates the doubleclick behaviour, see answer below for code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first try changing the security level to be low automatically instead of having the user define it:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;
```

If that doesn't work, try **also** calling the macro that enables the doubleClick behaviour from your c# code:

```
var xlapp = new Excel.Application();
xlapp.Visible = true;                        
xlapp.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;
xlapp.EnableEvents = true;
xlapp.Workbooks.Open(@"\\serverxy\bemuster\ap\" + "KV" + txtHv.Text + @"\" + "Ap.xls")

    string macro = "Module1.EnableRedirections";
    /// replace Module1 with whatever module you found the sub routine in

    try
    {
        xlapp.Run(macro);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Some error handling
    }
```

Comment: This solution did not solve the issue, unfortunately. If I doubleclick, it goes into the catch block. I added the VBA-Subprocedure to my initial post. This is the sub that is executed when doubleclicking into a cell.

Comment: You don't want to call the `DblClickHandle()` macro itself, you want to call the `EnableRedirections` macro - so the edit you suggested on the answer won't work. The `DblClickHandle()` is a routine that should only fire when double clicking, the `EnableRedirections` is telling Excel what to do WHEN you double click.

Comment: After inserting the module's name instead of the subprocedure's name it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. I'm not sure why you should have force `EnableRedirections`  to run, because when opening manually it seems to call automatically, so it SHOULD do the same even opening it via Excel.Interop... but at least we found a solution.